# Div background-image is not shown in print preview

Tags: javascript, background-image

Well i have the below code where div **background-image** and another image over background-image is not showing in the print preview.
All text fields are shown up except image and background-image.
I overlapped multiple input elements over background-image and an image over it also.
I couldn't identify the issue.

```js
document.getElementById("printButton").onclick = function() {
  printContent();
};

function printContent() {
  // Clone the printable content and append it to a new window
  var printableContent = document.getElementById("canvasSaved").cloneNode(true);

  var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'width=800,height=600');
  printWindow.document.body.appendChild(printableContent);

  // Trigger the print dialog for the new window
  printWindow.print();
  printWindow.close();
}
```

```css
.resizeME {
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div id="canvasSaved" class="canvasSaved col-lg-12" style="background-image: url('images/kacid.jpg'); background-size: contain; background-repeat: no-repeat; width: 100%; height: 512px; position: relative;">

  <input readonly id="charA" class="ar col-lg-8 resizeME" style="text-align: center; position: absolute; margin-top: 125px;
            background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); margin-left: 241px; transform: translateX(-50%); 
            color: black; border: none; font-weight: bold; font-size: 26px;" value="<?php echo $aname; ?>">

  <input id="charE" class="col-lg-8 resizeME" style="background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); text-align: center; position: absolute; margin-top: 174px; 
            margin-left: 241px; transform: translateX(-50%); color: black; border: none; 
            font-weight: bold; font-size: 26px;" value="<?php echo $ename; ?>">


  <input id="natE" style="background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); text-align: left; position: absolute;
            margin-top: 221px; margin-left: 258px; transform: translateX(-50%); 
            width: 203px; color: black; border: none; font-weight: bold; font-size: 26px;" value="<?php echo $cename; ?>" class="resizeME">

  <input id="natA" class="ar resizeME" style="background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); text-align: right; position: absolute;
            margin-top: 221px; margin-left: 421px; transform: translateX(-50%); 
            width: 125px; color: black; border: none; font-weight: bold; font-size: 21px;" value="<?php echo $caname; ?>">
  <input id="department" type="text" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); text-align: left; position: absolute;
            margin-top: 261px; margin-left: 272px; transform: translateX(-50%); 
            width: 392px; color: black; border: none; font-weight: bold;" value="<?php echo $dename; ?>" class="resizeME">

  <input id="title" type="text" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); text-align: left; position: absolute;
            margin-top: 312px; margin-left: 270px; transform: translateX(-50%); 
            width: 392px; color: black; border: none; font-weight: bold;" value="<?php echo $tename; ?>" class="resizeME">

  <input id="blood" type="text" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); text-align: left; position: absolute;
            margin-top: 351px; margin-left: 201px; transform: translateX(-50%); 
            width: 92px; color: black; border: none; font-weight: bold;" value="<?php echo $blename; ?>" class="resizeME">

  <input readonly id="staffnos" type="text" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); text-align: center; position: absolute;
            transform: translateX(-50%); 
            margin-top: 415px; margin-left: 588px; width: 193px; height: 28px; object-fit: cover;
            color: white; border: none; font-weight: bold; font-size: 30px;" value="<?php echo $staffno; ?>" class="resizeME">

  <input readonly id="date" type="text" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); text-align: center; position: absolute;
            transform: translateX(-50%); 
            margin-top: 406px; margin-left: 203px; width: 193px; height: 28px; object-fit: cover;
            color: black; border: none; font-weight: bold; font-size: 25px;" value="<?php echo $current_date; ?>" class="resizeME m_datepicker_2 form-control m-input">


  <span id="updatePhoto">
            <img src="images/employees/empPhotos/<?php echo $staffno.'.jpg'; ?>" 
            style="position: absolute; bottom: 101px; right: 6px; width: 199px;
            height: 225px; object-fit: cover; font-size: 26px;">
        </span>

</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/1.3.2/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="printButton">Click me to take a screenshot!</button>
```

Comment: most browser does not print background images to conserve ink and improve readability

Comment: there is an option in browser the print settings to enable printing background images

Comment: another way that instead of using background-image you can you <img> tag inside div

Comment: I tried to make a snippet. This is not a PHP issue to please change the mix of HTML and PHP to RENDERED HTML. The script gives console errors. Please click [edit], then scroll down and click "edit above snippet" and change the code to a [mcve] with an image from lorem pixel or other image CDNs

Comment: @HasanRaza it shows with that print backgrounds but now all the textfields movex a bit down

Comment: @mplungjan in my console there is no any error mixup is the demand as per requirement

Comment: Click the button here. Make a working [mcve]